# What does this basement floor drain look like beneath the surface?

Tags: plumbing, drain

This is the floor drain near my gas furnace. It handles the condensate line. I'd like to reconfigure it to also accept a water softener drain line, possibly by installing a larger bowl. I'm not sure how to open it up though. What type of drain is this, and how would I go about removing it from the pipe it's glued to?

The two areas that appear to be screw heads are not. They seem to be just molded into the plastic. I suspect that they are holes for screws to secure a cover that's no longer present.

[image]

Comment: That link looks right - you have a standard floor drain. It is PVC.  how would I go about removing it from the pipe it's glued to? You will end up digging - breaking concrete. Can you run your softener drain line and T into the condensate pipe so you don't need to touch the drain ?

Comment: A drain below the surface is anyone's guess. But if a proper P trap or U bend both would be OK

Comment: Isnt that the question here? Would we expect such drain to be properly plumbed into the septic system, and how to tell?  I have the exact same situation and elected to run the softener discharge over to the laundry tub drain just because i dont know where the floor drain goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice given in other answers. The crux of my question involved the design of the plumbing components, and I think I've found what it is. It seems to be this (with the steel grate missing):

[image]

<sub>[Image source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaefTAYQrUk)</sub>

I'll need to cut the pipe below the drain fitting and extend as necessary for my retrofit.

Answer (score 3):

The softener drain line is supposed to be air gapped about 2" from the drain water level to prevent growth of bacteria working its way back up the line.

If you fasten your lines to a piece of double strut (or other blocking) so they terminate  above the drain with a 90° fitting, then they can drain into the opening without a bowl. You could even extend the down leg into the opening to prevent splashing, as long as the softener doesn't touch anything.

Or, look for an adapter that could be inserted into the throat of the drain to add the bowl above.

Or, you will have to dig it up and replace it with your choice.

Comment: Good advice, but I'm hoping to make more space. The softener has two lines (one for overflow), and I'd also like to get the dehumidifier output going there. It's just too small for four lines without a bunch of splashing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just place a plastic funnel in the opening and hang the water softener drain line above it? Those two dimples 180 deg apart in the top piece suggests to me that the top cover with the hole unscrews or pops out with prying. Are there small screws in the two dimples? Or are those two dimples designed to receive screws to secure a grill over the top?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I'd have to raise the hard condensate line, and it would feel a bit amateurish. Just personal preference.

Comment: If the funnel has ribs on the outside it would allow the floor drain to function as a gravity drain for water getting on the floor while still catching the softener waste. Does the softener have brief high flow episodes or does it have a low continuous flow? There is going to be some solution that does not involve chiseling out concrete. What are those embossed circles around the perimeter of the plastic cover? Knockouts? Suggested places to drill?

Comment: Yeah, it's quite a jet. I think I'd prefer a sealed solution.